# Send params to Rails with key-value and file type, using REST client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postman, paw

#### In html, the params like this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tLy5M77xdhBr5pyQQsVw43T08THDNQ1z1yDdpC3oM0/jZR/lARPUF8wxNObFa2g/KgtGv5dW/mqDmXCtFmBFSQ==", "post"=>{"title"=>"test text tent"=>"34343", "tag_list"=>"fasd", "skill_list"=>"", "cover"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff22d2c0688 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/_g/7kks48cd1199yrsgzh965tq00000gn/T/RackMultipart20161011-93895-ub0blw.png>, @original_filename="28_logo.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[cover]\"; filename=\"28_logo.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "cover_cache"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Post", "id"=>"1"}
```

#### Without file upload,test by reset client use json only will look like this:

```
  Parameters: {"title"=>"test text ", "id"=>"1", "post"=>{"title"=>test text "}}
```

The problem is ,how could I send Parameters with file to serve on Rest Client/postman tool to use ruby on rails restful api?

**Expect wrapped format:**

```
{"title"=>"test text ", "id"=>"1", "post"=>{"title"=>test text ",'cover"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.....}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postman their is a two options beside field "value". You can choose file to add image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ,but I want get something like this  `Parameters: {"title"=>"test text ", "id"=>"1", "post"=>{"title"=>test text ",'cover"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.....}}`  how can't I wrap file into a json?